# Found THEN, expected ';' error

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm getting an error on the sql CASE statement below. It bombs on `(CASE WHEN SUM(ISNULL(OQ.Quantity,0) = 0 THEN SUM(R.Quantity) - SUM(R.Quantity * .9275))`. Can someone help? Thanks

```sql
CASE
    WHEN SUM(ISNULL(OQ.Quantity,0)) = 0 THEN SUM(R.Quantity * .9275)
    ELSE SUM(OQ.Quantity)
  END AS On_Time_Quantity,  

CASE
    WHEN SUM(ISNULL(OQ.Quantity,0)) > SUM(R.Quantity) THEN 0
    ELSE 
      **CASE WHEN SUM(ISNULL(OQ.Quantity,0) = 0 THEN SUM(R.Quantity) - SUM(R.Quantity * .9275))**
    ELSE 
      CASE WHEN SUM(ISNULL(OQ.Quantity,0) < SUM(R.Quantity) THEN SUM(R.Quantity) - SUM(ISNULL(OQ.Quantity,0))
  END
  END AS Late_Quantity,
```

Comment: Can you give us the whole query?

Comment: It's not letting me post the whole query because it's too long

Comment: I think you are missing a END. case when then else; case when then else case when then end end.... you have 3 case opened for 2 end. and i assumed ** in the code is just here to show where you receive an error?

Comment: Correct. I'll check the "end" suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Either have `THEN` on a new line or terminate the expression with colon before `THEN`:

```
CASE
  WHEN ... ; THEN
```

OR

```
CASE
  WHEN ...
  THEN
```

Comment: Marcell. Thank you for your quick response. I've added a ; before THEN, and I'm getting the following error now: Syntax error in SQL on line 328 symbol 49. Found 'THEN', expected 'Error when tokenlize'.  Thanks